# Unhide file extensions without logging out

Tags: batch-file, explorer

I use a batch file to quickly configure machines where I work with my preferred settings (disabling mouse acceleration, setting a black background, that sort of thing). I'd like to make it turn off the "Hide extensions for known file types" option in Explorer, and I have the following command for that:

`reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

However, this only takes effect on the next login, which is annoying. Is there a way to make the change effective immediately?

I've thought of a few possible solutions, but I'm not particularly happy with any of them.

- Pressing F5 works, and could be scripted with something like AutoHotKey, but this only works on the active window. I believe there's a way to get Explorer to refresh all windows, like what happens when you change a file association, but I'm not sure how.
- I could also kill and relaunch Explorer, but I wouldn't be able to run the script without losing every open Explorer window, and killing Explorer might cause data loss.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
    window.refresh2 3
Next
```

This vbscript works. It refreshes each explorer window.

To put the reg write in same file.

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Sh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideFileExt ", 0
```

Comment: Does this also work on the desktop view? While I'd rather not make the script an even bigger mess of disparate systems cobbled together by throwing VBS into the mix, I'll go ahead and mark it an answer if so.